# Run javascript code when output is rendered for default render methods (like onRender for widgets)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, htmlwidgets

In shiny apps we can add javascript code to run when a widget has rendered using `onRender` from `library(htmlwidgets)`. The same does not seem to work for the default `render*` functions from shiny. Is there a way to achieve something similar for these render functions?

The app below shows alerts whenever the plotly and leaflet widgets are rendered, but not for `renderUI` and `renderPlot`.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('a1','a1'),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width=6,
      plotlyOutput('plt'),
      plotOutput('p2')
    ),
    column(
      width=6,
      uiOutput('foo'),
      leafletOutput('map')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$foo <- renderUI({
    input$a1
    tagList(runif(1)) %>% 
      onRender('function() {alert("renderUI works");}')
  })
  output$plt <- renderPlotly({
    input$a1
    plot_ly(type='scatter', mode='markers', x=runif(10)) %>% 
      onRender('function() {alert("plotly works");}')
  })
  output$p2 <- renderPlot({
    input$a1
    hist(runif(50)) %>% 
      onRender('function() {alert("renderPlot works");}')
  })
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    input$a1
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      onRender('function() {alert("leaflet works");}')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onRender` refers to rendering a [htmlwidget](http://gallery.htmlwidgets.org/) not to shiny's render* functions.

You can use it [without shiny](https://plotly-r.com/js-event-handlers.html).

`onRender` expects a HTML widget object and accordingly doesn't work with e.g. tags - see `?onRender`:

> Use this function to supplement the widget's built-in JavaScript
> rendering logic with additional custom JavaScript code, just for this
> specific widget object.

You can use `library(shinyjs)` instead to realize a similar behaviour:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton('a1','a1'),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width=6,
      plotlyOutput('plt'),
      plotOutput('p2')
    ),
    column(
      width=6,
      uiOutput('foo'),
      leafletOutput('map')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$foo <- renderUI({
    input$a1
    runjs('alert("renderUI works");')
    tagList(p("p-tag"))
  })
  output$plt <- renderPlotly({
    input$a1
    plot_ly(type='scatter', mode='markers', x=runif(10)) %>% 
      onRender('function() {alert("plotly works");}')
  })
  output$p2 <- renderPlot({
    input$a1
    runjs('alert("renderPlot works");')
    hist(runif(50))
  })
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    input$a1
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      onRender('function() {alert("leaflet works");}')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you know how we can write raw JS to be used on the widget once rendered?